# What is the meaning of measure valued function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Are the term measure valued function is same as measurable function or it is a function which gives measure for every element in the domain of this function? Can someone provide one example of measure valued function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each real number $x$ define $\mu_x(E)=\mu(E+x)$ where $\mu$ is some fixed measure. Then the function $F(x)=\mu_x$ is  a measure valued function on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: By $E+ x$, you mean the set $\{ y+x ~|~ y \in E \}$.

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for your original source. In English, *measure-valued function* means a function that ranges in the set of measures (presumably) over some fixed space, much like what happens in [statistical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model), or when you consider the diverse possible convergences of sequences of measures. Therefore, there should be no reason to assume otherwise.

Comment: My motivation for this question comes from a population model for which the notion of measure valued solution is given.

Comment: So, this function will give a measure for each element in the domain. But how these functions are different from real valued functions.